# Do solutions of this system exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system

$$u' = u(1-u) - a_1u(v+w)$$

$$ v' = a_2vu - a_3v - a_4vw$$

$$ w'= a_4vw$$

Using the theorems of ODE, do solutions exist?  Are they unique?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Have you tried to find equilibrium points and do linear stability analysis?

Comment: I non-dimensionalized a model for predator prey with disease. I have done fixed point analysis, but the fixed points do funny things.  For instance, two fixed points do not rely on w, so there are infinitely many fixed points for choice of w.  That is what has me worried.

Comment: Cauchy-Lipschitz-Lindelöf theorem could be of interest.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy my experience in analysis is weak.  I'm not sure I can show that these functions are Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @DemetriP you don't need to show that these functions are Lipschitz-continuous. You need to show that the right-hand side of your system of ODE is locally Lipschitz-continuous function of $u,v,w$. Showing that the right-hand side is $C^1$ would be largely sufficient for that matter.

Comment: Ah, well, that is something I can do.  Thanks for the help.